# How to route the same url to different actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page that I'm rendering through the index action of a controller. I want to add a link to this page, which will reload the current page, but I want it to route to a different action first.

Here's what my routes.rb file looks like:

```
match 'users/:id/food' => 'foods#index', :as => :foods_show
match 'users/:id/food' => 'foods#sell', :as => :food_sell
```

And my link_to:

```
<%= link_to "Sell this Food", food_sell_path(current_user.id) %>
```

So the page is normally rendered via foods#index, but when a User clicks on this link, I want to reload the current page but via a different action than index.

Controller code:

```
def index
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @food = @user.foods
end

def sell
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @food = @user.foods
    redirect_to foods_show_path(@user.id), :notice => "You have sold one item!"
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't match the same url to different actions, since, basically, they are the same. You need to change something in the url, or change the verb (get, post, put, delete) or add some parameter to differentiate them.

For example, using `get` for index and `post` for sell:

```
get 'users/:id/food' => 'foods#index', :as => :foods_show
post 'users/:id/food' => 'foods#sell', :as => :food_sell
```

And in your link set the method to `post`:

```
<%= link_to "Sell this Food", food_sell_path(current_user.id, :_method => 'post') %>
```

Comment: Suppose I don't want either url to post the parameters in url. Like I don't want the GET request to post the params. What's the best way of going about this?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. In you don't change the verb then change something else.

Comment: Also, just to note, I had to modify your code slightly:
`<%= link_to "Sell this Food", food_sell_path(current_user.id), :method => 'post' %>`